# Error when trying to mass convert leads with Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads

I created a process to convert multiple leads at once when a button is clicked on a list view, I think I am in over my head because I don't have much experience with Apex, any help would be appreciated.

The error only happens when I process a certain amount of Leads, it works when there's a limited amount of Leads. I fear I am running into an issue with the governor limits but I'm not sure where I went wrong with this.

Here is the error:

> Error element Convert_The_Lead (FlowActionCall).An Apex error
> occurred: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on
> row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, There was an error converting
> the lead. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact
> your administrator.: []

Here is how the process works: The button is clicked on the list view, the button references a Visualforce page, the VF page references Lead as a standard controller and I passed a flow interview through the VF page,. The Flow grabs a collection of Lead records that fit the criteria of the list view, the Flow then uses an Apex class that converts the Leads. All of the code is below.

**VF Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">

<flow:interview name="AutoConvertLeadTest" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Lead/list?filterName=00B1T000009Ja0ZUAS')}"/>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code:**

```
public class AutoConvertLeads {

  @ InvocableMethod
  public static void assignLeads(List<Id> LeadIds){


    LeadStatus cLeadStatus=[Select Id,MasterLabel from LeadStatus where isConverted=true];

    List<Database.LeadConvert> massLeadConvert=new List<Database.LeadConvert>();


    for(Id currentLead:LeadIds){

      Database.LeadConvert LeadConvert=new Database.LeadConvert();

      LeadConvert.setLeadId(currentLead);
      LeadConvert.setConvertedStatus(cLeadStatus.MasterLabel);  
      LeadConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);

      massLeadConvert.add(LeadConvert);

    }

    if(!massLeadConvert.isEmpty()){

      List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr=Database.convertLead(massLeadConvert);

      system.debug('lcr:: +lcr');

    }


}

}
```

**Here is a photo of the Flow:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: N.B. `if(!massLeadConvert.isEmpty()` is unnecessary, DML on empty lists consumes no governor limit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're converting the leads in a loop. This is a Flow-based version of "executing DML in a loop" that you'd find in Apex. Collect all of the Id values into a Collection variable, then call your method.

Comment: N.B. invocable method signature will need to change to `List<List<Id>>`